# android retrofit encode "/" will be "\/"

Tags: android, retrofit, encode

This is raw data

```
"imageUrl": "https://xxxx.com/xxxx/imgame27035.png"
```

this is retrofit encode data

```
"ImageUrl": "https:\/\/xxxx.com\/xxxx\/imgame27035.png"
```

It seems that retrofit will change "/" into "\/",
so that imageUrl will be invalid.

How to fix it without some silly code like `str.replace("\/", "/")`